# STATICFILES on Django 1.6.2

Tags: python, django, django-settings

This is my `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

My structure is:

```
manage.py
myproject
-- __init__.py
-- settings.py
-- urls.py
-- wsgi.py
-- static
----- css
----- img
-------- logo.png
----- scripts
```

I use the static tag in my html file like this: `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.png">`

But, it is:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (logo.png, line 0)
```

I really can't understand this issue on Django 1.6.2 version.

Could someone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your error doesn't look like a Django error...  Also, if you view the source of the rendered page (in your browser), what is the URL of the image it's trying to fetch?

Comment: `<img src="/static/img/logo.png">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `django.contrib.staticfiles` app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    ...
)
```

Lastly, you need to make sure that `DEBUG` is set to `True` in `settings.py`.

**EDIT:**

Try removing `'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder'` from `STATICFILES_FINDERS`. Then run `$ python manage.py findstatic img/logo.png`

Comment: `django.contrib.staticfiles` is there and `DEBUG` is `True`

Comment: Try running ``$ python manage.py findstatic img/logo.png`` and see if it finds it correctly.

Comment: When I run it I get this error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The storage backend of the staticfiles finder <class 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder'> doesn't have a valid location.`