# Django 1.6.2 will not serve static content

Tags: python, django, file, static

I am **unable to serve static content** (for development purposes) using **Django==1.6.2**

**There is no error message** available to go with this.

I just end up with a 404 message on my browser and a 404 message in the dev server

```
[14/Apr/2014 16:50:29] "GET /static/resource/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1697
```

This is my set-up:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

 # Django extra
 'django.contrib.webdesign',
)


# All directories below have been checked and exist on disk.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'site_media/static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'site_media/media')
```

Content of main urls.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ADMIN
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # HOMEPAGE
    url(r'^$', 'mainmodule.views.home', name='home')

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Debug mode is turned on in settings.py

I have also tried the django.conf.urls.static method in my urls.py file but i end up with the same problem.

My static directory is not situated inside an app. I never had a problem with this and i cannot find any information regarding this on the official Django docs

I am able to run collectstatic with no problems.

URLS also resolve nicely inside my templates using {% static "....." %}.

**Relevant threads i have looked into (but haven't helped):**

[Can't get Django to serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463205/cant-get-django-to-serve-static-files)

[STATICFILES on Django 1.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339166/staticfiles-on-django-1-6-2)

Comment: Can you show your directory structure to show where your static files are located?

Comment: the static dir is inside site_media/static. site_media is inside the root folder structure. I can't seem to figure out how to post structured text inside a comment and for that i am truly sorry!

Comment: Try changing your `STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"`

Comment: Now the files linked from index.html are coming from /site_media/static/..... and still 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django development server doesn't know nor care about `STATIC_ROOT` or collected files. In order to correctly serve static files in development mode (aka using the `runserver` command) you should place your static files in:

1. A directory called `static` inside an app.
2. Any other directory listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Additionaly you should set `DEBUG` to True.

Comment: From what i can see static files **need** to be inside an app. This is how i got it to work just now. Also i tested wether django automatically discovers directories called 'static' inside apps. It does not. The directory needs to be listed in STATICFILES_DIRS. So, in order to serve static content with django, i need to put the resources inside an app and then rely on collectstatic to copy them to the target directory.

Comment: I see no point in that since on a production system another http server would be serving those files. There is no need to copy files somewhere and have them be copied somewhere else by collectstatic on a dev machine.

Comment: My 1st comment is wrong. Django will auto-discover the 'static' directory inside an app assuming it is listed in 'INSTALLED_APPS'. User yorodm is correct.

Comment: To use static data from the 'static' directory inside an app add `'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'` to your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` in the settings.

Comment: AppDirectoriesFinder is included in the default STATICFILES_FINDERS. there is no need to define it. See my comment above. I didn't list app in INSTALLED_APPS.